# Trying to make a div disappear with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a div disappear with javascript. It just doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">    
    document.getElementById("des").style.visibility = "hidden";    
</script>    

<div id="des">
  Text.
  <a href="">link</a>    
</div>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, being that you clearly don't mind using jquery, given that your snippet includes jquery - why don't you use jquery?

Comment: "It just doesn't work" is such a poor way to describe your problem. Check for errors in your console. You probably could have figured it out on your own since it would be telling that you're getting the JavaScript equivalent of a NullPointerException since your `#des` is not yet rendered

Comment: Why exactly are you using JS?  Is it just for learning purposes or for actual application?  If it is the former, then fine.  But, if this is for your production code, then I suggest you just use straight up CSS.

Comment: @DRD There are cases where it doesn't make sense to use CSS. Are you suggesting creating a class called `.hidden` and applying that to the element? It won't solve the problem and it's also not very semantic.

Comment: @neminem I am not a professional programmer so I combine code from tutorials so some use one thing others use a different thing. When I combine them I get lost in them and since I am not too experienced it turns into a weird mix.

Comment: @JuanMendes: By the looks of his code, he is trying to hide the `div` once the page loads.  Why use JS for that?  Makes no sense at all.

Comment: @DRD Yeah, I am assuming the OP is not really just trying to hide it when it's first displayed, that could be what he or she is trying to do

Comment: I was just testing to see if the div disappears. What I really want to do is have the text at the top of the page go away after the user has logged in. So next I will have to figure out how to determine if the user is logged in. I am not even sure if I have to do that in javascript or php.

Comment: @JeromeWasBannedBySONazis If you were going to do it after determining if the user is logged in. you probably wouldn't have encountered the problem.   http://stackoverflow.com/a/25209851/227299 was the first correct answer. You should mark that as the accepted one (after you verify it) by clicking the tick next to it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are running the script before the DOM has loaded.

If you put the script after the div, it works

Comment: @MattD Putting it immediately after the HTML makes it run even faster so that it won't even have a chance to flash on slow machines/very long documents

Comment: @JuanMendes True, I was more or less noting there were other options. However, if the `div` is supposed to be hidden on page load, it seems the better design choice would simply be to set its `display` attribute to none, and then for OP to write his script for when it should be displayed.

Comment: @MattD Yeah, from what the OP has said, they are going to make a call to see if the user is logged in and then hide it. Probably would be better to have it hidden and then show it.

Answer (score 5):

Try and throw a document ready around your code.

And if you are loading jquery you can just do `$('#des').css('visibility', 'hidden');` or `$('#des').hide()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#des').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to get the element with id = "des", before it's created.

```
<div id="des">
    Text.
<a href="">link</a>

</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("des").style.visibility = "hidden";

</script>
```

This should work.

Comment: OP can also wrap the code in `$(document).ready` and place it in the header.

Answer (score 3):

You should wrap the script in a `$(document).ready` block because you are calling the script before the DOM is loaded.

So,You will have to do it like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
     document.getElementById("des").style.visibility = "hidden";
   });   
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

this worked for me when I placed the javascript code in a function and load it when the body loads e.g

```
<script>
  function func(){
    document.getElementById("der").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
</script>

<body onload=func()>
  <div id="der">
    test
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not to use JQuery `hide()` method, as you already using JQuery and obiviously code to be included either in `$(document).ready(function(){\\some code})` or `$(window).load(function(){\\some code})`;

```
$('#des').hide()
```

in JS, you can achieve by

```
document.getElementById("des").style.display = "none";
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25209851/227299 This is not much different than what the OP is doing

Answer (score 2):

It's:

```
document.getElementById("des").style.display = "none";
```

you can also use:

```
document.getElementById("des").style.display = "block";
```

to make it visible again.

That's my preferred method, at any rate.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait for the document to be ready. Try using:

`$( document ).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById("des").style.visibility = "hidden";
});`

or you could use JQuery:

`$(documet).ready(function() {
   $( ".des" ).hide();
});`

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is an interepreter based language, in case you want to write script first and use later, add a function instead.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">    
    function hideMyDiv(){
       document.getElementById("des").style.visibility = "hidden";    
    }
</script>    

<div id="des">
  Text.
  <a href="">link</a>    
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">    
   hideMyDiv();
</script>
```

Cheers !!