# advice for getting text from clicking an image in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Main Page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = "hi";
}
//function getImage() {
    //var img1 = document.getElementById("1").addEventListener('click', onClick());
//}

</script>
<p>
<img id="1" src="hamster.jpg" onclick="myFunction()">
<img id="2" src="fish.jpg">
<img id="3" src="dog.jpg">
<img id="4" src="fries.jpg">
<img id="5" src="pop.jpg">
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I have so far. I am trying to get text to appear by the image after it has been clicked. I am trying to link the image to the javascript function and then have it get the element ID and give text. Does anyone have any advice? Am I on the right track trying it this way? So far it is returning nothing.

Comment: `img` is an empty element, innerHTML does nothing with it. You have to prepare some placeholders for the text under your images.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you, you want to replace that image in a text?
If so add:

```
<div id="targetId">
    <img id="1" src="hamster.jpg" onclick="myFunction()">
</div>
```

and in your javascript function use:

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("targetId").innerHTML = "hi";
}
```

If you want to make the text appear nearby the image use:

```
<p>
    <img id="1" src="hamster.jpg" onclick="myFunction()">
    <div id="targetId"></div>
    <img id="2" src="fish.jpg">
    <img id="3" src="dog.jpg">
    <img id="4" src="fries.jpg">
    <img id="5" src="pop.jpg">
</p>
```

Comment: I actually want to have the text appear by the image when clicked, not replace the image...

Comment: if I wanted to have it where if I click an image text will appear and then when I click another image the text would disappear and the second image text would appear, do I need more javascript?

Comment: Basically you don't need another javascript function for that, but if you want to make it disappear read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209834/trying-to-make-a-div-disappear-with-javascript) answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "hi";
}
```

```html
<div id="a1" onclick="myFunction()"><img id="a" src="hamster.jpg" "></div>
<div id="text"></div>
<img id="b" src="fish.jpg">
<img id="c" src="dog.jpg">
<img id="d" src="fries.jpg">
<img id="e" src="pop.jpg">
```

You should wrap your image inside a div. Don't name your ids with just a number.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using jquery to help you out on this. In this way you can find all the relevant images, set up the click and easily add the text you need in the right way. The following is a complete example working example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Main Page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>
    <img id="1" src="hamster.jpg" />
    <img id="2" src="fish.jpg" />
    <img id="3" src="dog.jpg" />
    <img id="4" src="fries.jpg" />
    <img id="5" src="pop.jpg" />
  </p>

  <script type='text/javascript'>
      // find all <img>s inside a <p> and set up onclick
      $('p img').on('click', function() {
          // add the text after the clicked element
          $(this).after('hi');
      });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if I just want the text below the image and not have it replace the image?

Comment: this doesn't replace the image, it just adds new text after the image. You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/jj00x7dw/

Comment: When I run that code in a browser to test it does not get the text.